# Record with Parent ID are stored in a flat table need a list of all children(including descendants)

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, common-table-expression

I have table with records like this tried using CTE but very noob in DB related stuff and browsed through couple of articles similar to this but most of them are talking about getting list of parents not children.

```
ID  Parent ID   Ultimate record
1     --              Yes
2     1           No
3     1           No
4     2           No
5     2           No
6     1           No
```

Expected result

```
ID      Child       Level
1       2           1
1       3           1
1       4           2
1       5           2
1       6           3
2       4           1
2       5           1
2       6           2
5       6           1
```

Comment: which dbms are you using? have you tried anything?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Also, you are supposed to atleast try it out yourself first.

Comment: Added DB and shared the details of my RnD